# How many time intervals do I need for a DFS in a graph?

Tags: c++, time, graph, queue, depth-first-search

**Problem:**

Let's say you are doing a breadth first search on a graph. You start at a specific point and then spread outwards. During one time interval and under a given condition you "infect" your neighbors. I want to know how many time-intervals it takes to traverse the entire graph (i.e. infect all nodes).

This question is a general question. However, I will lean on a LeetCode example to provide something that is reproducible.

**My approach:**

[Basic bfs using a queue](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/breadth-first-search-or-bfs-for-a-graph/). During each iteration, I insert a spacer element to the queue. If I find this spacer, I know one time interval is up.

elements in queue `q`:

```
q: a, b, c, timer // a, b and c are infected at first moment in time
q: d, e, timer    // above elements infect, d and e.
q: timer          // we only have a timer, total traversal took 2 time intervals
```

**Why my approach does not work:**

The basic flaw in my approach is that I might push elements to `q` multiple times, if they will get infected from multiple sides.

Example grid with queue `q`. `q` stored indices of nodes in graph.  `1` is healthy, `2` is infected:

```
1,1
2,2

q: {0,0}, {0,1}, timer // top 2 elements are in queue. They got infected by bottom 2 elements.
```

process first element

```
2,1
2,2

q: {0,1}, timer, {0,1}
```

process 2nd element

```
2,2
2,2

q: timer, {0,1}, timer
```

We push the same element to `q` twice, leading to an incorrect time. (time == 2, instead of time == 1).

**How can I fix this error?**

**Example problem taken from LeetCode:**

My approach used to (not) solve [LeetCode problem 994](https://leetcode.com/problems/rotting-oranges/).

```
class Solution {
    struct position {
        position(size_t i, size_t j) : i_(i), j_(j), valid_(true) {}
        position(bool valid) : i_(0), j_(0), valid_(valid) {}
        
        const size_t i_;
        const size_t j_;
        const bool valid_;
    };
    
public:
    int orangesRotting(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
        if (grid.empty()) return -1;
        size_t fresh_orange = 0;
        std::queue<position> q;
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < grid.size(); ++i) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < grid.at(0).size(); ++j) {
                int orange = grid.at(i).at(j);
                if (orange == 1) {
                    ++fresh_orange;
                } else if (orange == 2) {
                    q.emplace(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        size_t minutes = 0;
        q.emplace(false);
        
        while(!q.empty()) {
            const position pos = q.front();
            q.pop();
            if (!pos.valid_ && !q.empty()) {
                ++minutes;
                q.emplace(false);
            }
            if (!pos.valid_) continue;
            
            // bfs next: top, right, bottom, left
            const size_t old_size = q.size();
            if (pos.i_ > 0) 
                if (grid.at(pos.i_ - 1).at(pos.j_) == 1) q.emplace(pos.i_ - 1, pos.j_);
            if (pos.j_ < grid.at(0).size() - 1)
                if (grid.at(pos.i_).at(pos.j_ + 1) == 1) q.emplace(pos.i_, pos.j_ + 1);
            if (pos.i_ < grid.size() - 1)
                if (grid.at(pos.i_  + 1).at(pos.j_) == 1) q.emplace(pos.i_  + 1, pos.j_);
            if (pos.j_ > 0)
                if (grid.at(pos.i_).at(pos.j_ - 1) == 1) q.emplace(pos.i_, pos.j_ - 1);
        
            if (grid.at(pos.i_).at(pos.j_) == 1) {
                --fresh_orange;
                grid.at(pos.i_).at(pos.j_) = 2;
            }
        }

        return fresh_orange == 0 ? minutes : -1;
    }
};
```

Input that reproduces my problem: `[[2,2],[1,1],[0,0],[2,0]]`.

Comment: Normally with a BFS you know whether a given node has been visited before, so why not only store the (by definition) lowest time when you update `visited`?

Comment: My approach is different  @Botje. I do not store the time intervals of when a node got infected. I keep track of the current time in the queue. There is no `visited` array. There is only a graph that has the states `{infected, not infected, soon infected, empty}` and a queue which stores the infections in flight for this and the next time interval

Answer (score 0):

Okay. I have the (obvious) solution: You just keep track of who will get infected in the next round. I am using `-1` as a marker for "will get infected soon".

Example grid with queue `q`. `q` stored indices of nodes in graph.  `1` is healthy, `2` is infected:

```
-1,-1
 2, 2

q: {0,0}, {0,1}, timer // top 2 elements are in queue. They got infected by bottom 2 elements.
```

process first element

```
 2,-1
 2, 2

q: {0,1}, timer, // we do not push back {0,1} since we know it will have symptoms soon
```

process 2nd element

```
2,2
2,2

q: time
```

To those of you that are interested in the LeetCode solution:

```
class Solution {
    struct position {
        position(size_t i, size_t j) : i_(i), j_(j), valid_(true) {}
        position(bool valid) : i_(0), j_(0), valid_(valid) {}
        
        const size_t i_;
        const size_t j_;
        const bool valid_;
    };
    
public:
    int orangesRotting(vector<vector<int>>& grid) {
        if (grid.empty()) return -1;
        size_t fresh_orange = 0;
        std::queue<position> q;
        
        for (size_t i = 0; i < grid.size(); ++i) {
            for (size_t j = 0; j < grid.at(0).size(); ++j) {
                int orange = grid.at(i).at(j);
                if (orange == 1) {
                    ++fresh_orange;
                } else if (orange == 2) {
                    q.emplace(i, j);
                }
            }
        }
        size_t minutes = 0;
        q.emplace(false);
        
        while(!q.empty()) {
            const position pos = q.front();
            q.pop();
            if (!pos.valid_ && !q.empty()) {
                ++minutes;
                q.emplace(false);
            }
            if (!pos.valid_) continue;
            
            // bfs next: top, right, bottom, left
            const size_t old_size = q.size();
            if (pos.i_ > 0) {                
                if (grid.at(pos.i_ - 1).at(pos.j_) == 1) {
                    grid.at(pos.i_ - 1).at(pos.j_) = -1;
                    q.emplace(pos.i_ - 1, pos.j_);
                }
            }
            if (pos.j_ < grid.at(0).size() - 1) {
                if (grid.at(pos.i_).at(pos.j_ + 1) == 1) {
                    grid.at(pos.i_).at(pos.j_ + 1) = -1;
                    q.emplace(pos.i_, pos.j_ + 1);
                }
            }
            if (pos.i_ < grid.size() - 1) {
                if (grid.at(pos.i_  + 1).at(pos.j_) == 1) {
                    grid.at(pos.i_  + 1).at(pos.j_) = -1;
                    q.emplace(pos.i_  + 1, pos.j_);
                }
            }
            if (pos.j_ > 0) {
                if (grid.at(pos.i_).at(pos.j_ - 1) == 1) {
                    grid.at(pos.i_).at(pos.j_ - 1) = -1;
                    q.emplace(pos.i_, pos.j_ - 1);
                }
            }
                
            if (grid.at(pos.i_).at(pos.j_) == 1 || grid.at(pos.i_).at(pos.j_) == -1) {
                --fresh_orange;
                grid.at(pos.i_).at(pos.j_) = 2;
            }
        }

        return fresh_orange == 0 ? minutes : -1;
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

#### Looks pretty good!

- Here is another approach (depth first search) using `std::count_if`:

```
// The following block might slightly improve the execution time;
// Can be removed;
static const auto __optimize__ = []() {
    std::ios::sync_with_stdio(false);
    std::cin.tie(nullptr);
    std::cout.tie(nullptr);
    return 0;
}();

// Most of headers are already included;
// Can be removed;
#include <cstdint>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>

static const struct Solution {
    static const int orangesRotting(
        std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grid
    ) {
        ValueType minutes = 0;
        ValueType fresh = 0;

        for (ValueType row = 0; row < std::size(grid); ++row) {
            fresh += std::count_if(std::begin(grid[row]), std::end(grid[row]), [&](ValueType cell) {
                return cell == 1;
            });
        }

        for (ValueType prev_fresh = fresh; fresh > 0; ++minutes) {
            for (ValueType row = 0; row < std::size(grid); ++row) {
                for (ValueType col = 0; col < std::size(grid[row]); ++col) {
                    if (grid[row][col] == minutes + 2) {
                        fresh -= isRotten(grid, row + 1, col, minutes) +
                                 isRotten(grid, row - 1, col, minutes) +
                                 isRotten(grid, row, col + 1, minutes) +
                                 isRotten(grid, row, col - 1, minutes);
                    }
                }
            }

            if (fresh == std::exchange(prev_fresh, fresh)) {
                return -1;
            }
        }

        return minutes;
    }

  private:
    using ValueType = std::uint_fast16_t;
    static const bool isRotten(
        std::vector<std::vector<int>>& grid,
        const int row,
        const int col,
        const int minutes
    ) {
        if (
            row < 0 || row >= std::size(grid) ||
            col < 0 || col >= std::size(grid[row]) ||
            grid[row][col] != 1
        ) {
            return false;
        }

        grid[row][col] = minutes + 3;
        return true;
    }
};
```